# Take data from a.href inside of loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm using a `bs4` to **scrape** some date from a webpage.
I'm using this

```py
for h2 in soup.find_all('div', class_='p-item-content-info'):
    #print(h2.prettify())
    x = h2.select('.p-item-title')
    x2 = h2.select('.p-item-most-important')
    x3 = x + x2
    print(x3)
    print("##############################")
```

To find the `p-item-content-info` article on page(with 3 elements inside `(h3 class=p-item-title)`,`(div class=p-item-important-field`), `(div class=p-item-detail)`) and print `title`(.p-item-title) and `price`(.p-item-most-important) which is inside of `p-item-important-field`. But it shows much more data that I want.
This is the output

```
[<h3 class="p-item-title">
<a href="https://jmty.jp/aichi/car-mit/alliance-g_700020691130190531003?ex=1&amp;initial=gnt" rel="nofollow">三菱 アイ Ｌ　禁煙車　スマートキー　ナビ　ＴＶ　Ｔチェーン （なし）</a>
</h3>, <div class="p-item-most-important">
65,000円
</div>]
```

And I would like to have that `a href`- link, `title` - that japanese and `price`-that number. How should I change the loop to get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select` returns a list of elements, either index it with `[0]` to get the first one, or use `select_one`, and `element.text` to get only the text out of the tags:

```
for h2 in soup.find_all('div', class_='p-item-content-info'):
    x = h2.select_one('.p-item-title').text
    x2 = h2.select_one('.p-item-most-important').text
    x3 = x + x2
    print(x3)
    print("##############################")
```